# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for Logarithmic Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am trying to calculate the MLE for the logarithmic distribution.
It holds

$$ P(X=k) = -\frac{p^k}{k \cdot \ln(1-p} $$

Thus, the ML function is

$$L_p(X_1,\dots, X_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} -\frac{p^{x_i}}{x_i \cdot \ln(1-p)} = p^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(1-p)}\right)^n \prod_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{x_i} $$

and the log likelihood function is

\begin{align}
\log L_p(X_1,\dots,X_n)& = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \log(p) + n \cdot \log\left(\frac{1}{\log(1-p)}\right) + \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{x_i}\right) 
\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \log(p) + n \cdot -\log(\log(1-p)) + \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{x_i}\right)
\end{align}

So:

$$\frac{\partial L_p}{\partial p} = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + n \frac{1}{\log(1-p)(1-p)} \overset{!}{=} 0$$

This is equivalent to:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = - \frac{p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)}$$

Now I don't know how to go on. How do I get the estimator for $p$?

Thanks in advance, for helping !

Comment: All you can say is that the MLE $\hat p$ satisfies $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = - \frac{\hat p}{\log(1-\hat p)(1-\hat p)}$. I guess you have to use numerical methods to solve for $\hat p$.

Comment: Thank you @StubbornAtom. I think that result should be enough, I am preparing for an exam, I think during the exam I have no numerical means available, too.

Comment: I worry a bit about taking a log in a term $log(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n-\frac{1}{x_i})$. For odd $i$ you take a log of negative number.

Answer (score 1):

*I precise that I am not familiar with this domains you tagged.*

Let me suppose that you look for $p$ such that
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = - \frac{p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)}$$ where the value of the lhs is known.

This is the same as  solving for $p$ the equation
$$-\frac 1p \log(1-p)(1-p) =a \qquad \text{where} \qquad a=\frac n{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$ and the lhs is a pretty nice function (plot it).

A *very simplistic approximation* of the lhs is
$$-\frac 1p \log(1-p)(1-p) \sim 1-\frac 12(p^{1.3}+p^{2.6})$$ which would give as an *estimate*
$$p_0=\Bigg[\frac{\sqrt{9-8 a}-1}{2}\Bigg]^{\frac {10}{13}} $$
The solution will be easily obtained using very few iterations of Newton method
$$p_{n+1}=\frac{p_n ((a+1) p_n+(2-p_n) \log (1-p_n))}{p_n+\log (1-p_n)}$$

Just to show a few numbers

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a    &  p_0     &  p_1  & p_2    & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & 0.973965 & 0.990822 & 0.989085 &  0.989044 \\
 0.10 & 0.947100 & 0.975995 & 0.973133 &  0.973082 \\
 0.15 & 0.919331 & 0.956826 & 0.953390 &  0.953343 \\
 0.20 & 0.890577 & 0.933684 & 0.930116 &  0.930080 \\
 0.25 & 0.860741 & 0.906737 & 0.903375 &  0.903350 \\
 0.30 & 0.829712 & 0.876061 & 0.873142 &  0.873127 \\
 0.35 & 0.797359 & 0.841674 & 0.839341 &  0.839333 \\
 0.40 & 0.763526 & 0.803555 & 0.801865 &  0.801861 \\
 0.45 & 0.728024 & 0.761651 & 0.760580 &  0.760578 \\
 0.50 & 0.690622 & 0.715880 & 0.715332 &  0.715332 \\
 0.55 & 0.651034 & 0.666131 & 0.665952 &  0.665952 \\
 0.60 & 0.608897 & 0.612262 & 0.612254 &  0.612254 \\
 0.65 & 0.563738 & 0.554098 & 0.554036 &  0.554036 \\
 0.70 & 0.514924 & 0.491419 & 0.491084 &  0.491084 \\
 0.75 & 0.461572 & 0.423957 & 0.423166 &  0.423166 \\
 0.80 & 0.402390 & 0.351379 & 0.350039 &  0.350039 \\
 0.85 & 0.335341 & 0.273265 & 0.271443 &  0.271441 \\
 0.90 & 0.256830 & 0.189082 & 0.187101 &  0.187099 \\
 0.95 & 0.159033 & 0.098164 & 0.096722 &  0.096722
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

A better $p_0$ can be generated approximating
$$f(p)=-(1-p)\log(1-p)\qquad \text{by} \qquad g(p)=p(1-p)(\alpha+\beta p+\gamma p^2)$$
Minimizing, with respect to $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ the norm
$$\Phi(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\int_0^1 \big[f(p)-g(p)\big]^2\,dp$$ leads to
$$\alpha=-\frac{49}{20}\qquad \qquad \beta=\frac{203}{60}\qquad \qquad \gamma=-\frac{259}{120}$$ which makes that we need now to solve for $p$ the equation
$$p(1-p)(\alpha+\beta p+\gamma p^2)= ap$$ which is a cubic with one real root given by
$$p_0=\frac{1}{63} \left(29-\sqrt{1298} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{649} \sqrt{\frac{2}{649}} (102060
   a-72403)\right)\right)\right)$$ The iterates will be
$$p_{n+1}=\frac{p_n+\log (1-p_n)}{\log (1-p_n)+1-a}$$
Repeating the same table as before
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a    &  p_0     &  p_1  & p_2    & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & 0.981261 & 0.989673 & 0.989050 &  0.989044 \\
 0.10 & 0.961424 & 0.973919 & 0.973087 &  0.973082 \\
 0.15 & 0.940327 & 0.954123 & 0.953346 &  0.953343 \\
 0.20 & 0.917764 & 0.930652 & 0.930081 &  0.930080\\
 0.25 & 0.893478 & 0.903668 & 0.903351 &  0.903350 \\
 0.30 & 0.867132 & 0.873231 & 0.873127 &  0.873127 \\
 0.35 & 0.838282 & 0.839336 & 0.839333 &  0.839333 \\
 0.40 & 0.806326 & 0.801910 & 0.801861 &  0.801861 \\
 0.45 & 0.770425 & 0.760804 & 0.760578 &  0.760578 \\
 0.50 & 0.729386 & 0.715776 & 0.715332 &  0.715332 \\
 0.55 & 0.681491 & 0.666490 & 0.665953 &  0.665952 \\
 0.60 & 0.624389 & 0.612589 & 0.612254 &  0.612254 \\
 0.65 & 0.555658 & 0.554043 & 0.554036 &  0.554036 \\
 0.70 & 0.475971 & 0.491719 & 0.491085 &  0.491084 \\
 0.75 & 0.393972 & 0.426015 & 0.423189 &  0.423166 \\
 0.80 & 0.320678 & 0.353488 & 0.350077 &  0.350039 \\
 0.85 & 0.259426 & 0.272093 & 0.271443 &  0.271441 \\
 0.90 & 0.208371 & 0.189219 & 0.187125 &  0.187099 \\
 0.95 & 0.164984 & 0.117574 & 0.099978 &  0.096722
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I suspect that you have to write the log likelihood function as

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot \log(p) + n \cdot \log\left(\frac{-1}{\log(1-p)}\right) + \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}\right)
$$

since $log(1-p)$ is negative, so $log(\frac{1}{log(1-p)})$ is undefined. I got the same final equation as you for the MLE, though.

I don't see a way to get a closed form solution, so I think you need to use numerical methods/root-finding algorithms to find the root(s) of
$$\frac{1}{\hat{p}} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + n \frac{1}{\log(1-\hat{p})(1-\hat{p})} = 0$$